# Animate start page with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a doubt with the use of animations in AngularJS 1.3, I have an index.html with a full background image and h1, p, input etc... tags, and I want to animate the init page load, for example apply a Fade in effect on the start. I know there is libraries like Animate.css, but with AngularJS how I would can do that?

I saw AngularJS animations with ng-enter, ng-hide etc ... but how animate entire index page?, I don't want to animate by parts.

Comment: Just a fast comment, If I were you, I would make a global scope for ex scope.readyStart. Starting with a value of false and when the all of the controllers init ready change this value to true.

In the markup only put an ng-class (or data-ng-class) with a relation to this scope variable. (only add the class if its true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fade in the entire page from white you could simply do this using `ng-cloak`, or you can set whatever background-color/background you want on the body and `ng-cloak` the container of the content you want to fade in.

```
[ng-cloak] {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
.element-with-initial-ng-cloak {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```